# How do I force GAS to generate output identical to input?

Tags: c, optimization, mips, gnu-assembler

I want to write code that has a public C interface, but is otherwise implemented entirely in MIPS, mainly as a learning exercise. However, I'm stuck fighting GAS because it seems to assume it knows better than I do.

To illustrate, let's say I want to implement the following in MIPS:

```
int bar(void)
{
    return (4 / 2);
}
```

As I mentioned above, I want to be able to call ASM routines from C, so we'll need a C code file, bar.c, as well as the MIPS assembly in bar.S.

bar.c:

```
extern int bar(void);

void _start()
{
    int foo = bar();
}
```

bar.S:

```
.global bar .text

bar:
    addi $2, $0, 4
    addi $3, $0, 2
    div $2, $3
    mflo $2
    jr $31
    addu $3, $0, $0
```

`mipsel-none-elf-gcc bar.c bar.S -o bar.elf -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib` successfully compiles this, but `mipsel-none-elf-objdump -d bar.elf` shows that GAS is messing with my bar() code:

```
00400050 <bar>:
  400050:       20020004        addi    v0,zero,4
  400054:       20030002        addi    v1,zero,2
  400058:       14600002        bnez    v1,400064 <bar+0x14>
  40005c:       0043001a        div     zero,v0,v1
  400060:       0007000d        break   0x7
  400064:       2401ffff        li      at,-1
  400068:       14610004        bne     v1,at,40007c <bar+0x2c>
  40006c:       3c018000        lui     at,0x8000
  400070:       14410002        bne     v0,at,40007c <bar+0x2c>
  400074:       00000000        nop
  400078:       0006000d        break   0x6
  40007c:       00001012        mflo    v0
  400080:       00001012        mflo    v0
  400084:       03e00008        jr      ra
  400088:       00000000        nop
  40008c:       00001821        move    v1,zero
```

I don't want the division checks, or delay slot fixups, or the assembler being "helpful" in any way here: I'm perfectly capable of handling those things myself if necessary. How do I tell GAS to just be a dumb assembler?

Comment: Maybe this is helpfulm at least for the zero check: https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2010-01/msg00386.html

Comment: @Gene You should add this comment as an answer. "div $0, $2, $3" gets rid of the zero checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was solved in the comments. GAS accepts a 3-operand version of `div` where division checks are disabled if the first operand is `$0`. As for the delay slot, a `.set noreorder` directive prevents reordering of instructions (duh). Changing the assembly to:

```
.set noreorder

.global bar .text

bar:
    addi $2, $0, 4
    addi $3, $0, 2
    div $0, $2, $3
    mflo $2
    jr $31
    addu $3, $0, $0
```

produces the correct output:

```
00400050 <bar>:
  400050:       20020004        addi    v0,zero,4
  400054:       20030002        addi    v1,zero,2
  400058:       0043001a        div     zero,v0,v1
  40005c:       00001012        mflo    v0
  400060:       03e00008        jr      ra
  400064:       00001821        move    v1,zero
```

Comment: The more correct explanation is that the 2 operand pneumonic is a macro name. The 3 operand form is an instruction.